# how to use memcache to speed-up rails/heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, heroku, memcached

Heroku supports memcache natively as an addon. my problem is, being a rails newbie still, I have no clue how to use memcache in order to speed-up my most time-consuming request (I know which they are by looking a the newrelic analysis). should we use a gem like 'cache-money' on-top of memcache? does anyone use act_as_cached anymore?

I know this is a pretty trivial questions. Yet after searching the web for hours, I could not find a decent tutorial. Any help/link appreciated!

Comment: Caching is a very broad topic and you can do many different types of it. Memcached is nothing special; it's just a storage medium for things you want to cache (as mysql may be your storage for objects you want to be persistent). Another type of caching may be more suited for your particular page. In any case, you'll need to give us more details about your slow request in order to get decent answers. What kind of page is it? Public, or different for each user? Is most of the time spent in querying the database, or rendering the views?

Comment: +1 for this question. I'm also seeking a decent rails + memcache tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can watch [Caching in Rails 2.1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/115-caching-in-rails-2-1) and then read the [memcached documentation](http://docs.heroku.com/memcache) (I suppose you have already read it) in Heroku.

Also, [Touch and Cache](http://railscasts.com/episodes/172-touch-and-cache) is quite interesting technique to avoid writing Sweepers in order to delete cached content when you need to refresh the cached data. Using touch will auto expire cached data with almost no need to write new code.

Please note that today, the Heroku memcached integration assumes you are using Rails >= 2.3.3

The main idea is that you add the result(s) of your time consuming method to Rails.cache (which is the interface through which you access your caching mechanism). When you fetch that result(s) the caching mechanism searches to see if it can find it or if it hasn't expired.

If it finds it, it returns it very fast because it takes it from the cache.

If it doesn't find it or it has expired (you set this when you call fetch), it runs the actual slow method to add it or refresh it in cache.

Finally, it is very useful to read the Rails documentation apart from whether you are using memcached or the built in Rails caching: [Caching with Rails: An overview](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html). Among other things it talks about:

- Page caching
- Action caching
- Fragment caching
- Sweepers
- SQL caching
- and more ...

Answer (score 0):

You can cache on memcache the action_cache or you can access to memcache with Rails.cache